# ImplicitCast_ error when returning a pointer to std::list of pointers

Tags: c++, googlemock

So I have this little problem.  I have class that I'm trying to mock but I'm getting an error. The method in question, is returning a pointer to an std::list of object pointers. Below is some code that replicates the problem:

```
#include <ByteBuffer.h>
. . .
class Foo {
public:
    std::list<ByteBuffer*>* getStuff() { return new std::list<ByteBuffer*>(); }
};

class MockFoo : public Foo {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(getStuff, std::list<ByteBuffer>*());
};

TEST_F(FooTest, shouldDoStuff) {
    MockFoo* mfoo = new MockFoo();
    std::list<ByteBuffer*>* plist = new std::list<ByteBuffer*>();
    EXPECT_CALL(*mfoo, getStuff()).WillOnce(Return(plist));
}
```

When I compile this, I'm getting the following error:

```
/usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-actions.h:491: error: no matching function for call to ‘ImplicitCast_(std::list<zios::common::ByteBuffer*, std::allocator<zios::common::ByteBuffer*> >*&)’
make: *** [Debug/FooTest.o] Error 1
```

Can someone tell me what's causing this?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This looks wrong:

```
MOCK_METHOD0(getStuff, std::list<ByteBuffer>*());
```

Should be:

```
MOCK_METHOD0(getStuff, std::list<ByteBuffer*>*());
```

Should being relative to coding standards in use, I don't recommend non-wrapped pointers in `std::list`...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, in googlemock you can mock only virtual methods.
So, your method "getStuff( )" in class "Foo" should be virtual.

Comment: Both right. However the problem in my real code still persists. I thought I had duplicated it here but obviously not.:(  Thanks!

Comment: @user1143970 Please copy-paste your "real" code... It never works trying to re-create an untested sample.  If you must then ***splat*** the parts that are sensitive.